# Small business using iPads needs to allow access to documents stored on office computer

Tags: ipad, icloud

I am currently running a small business with Sales people and installers. I have issued each one of them an iPad to take with them on consultations. I am currently looking around for a program that would allow all of the iPad users to access product info documents that are stored on our office computer. But here is the kicker… I want the files to automatically upload to the devices when they return to the office, but I don't want the installers to receive files related to sales, and I don't want the sales people to receive files related to the installers.

I was trying to do some research on how iCloud works, but everything I was able to find was quite vague. I've also thought about drop box, but again I'm not confident that it can do what I'm looking to do.

Is there anything out there that will function the way I need?

Comment: Dropbox is your way.

Answer (score 4):

I would use Dropbox for this, creating separate repositories for Sales and Installers.

Any changes made on each device will sync back to DropBox, and any changes on DropBox will sync back to the individual devices.

My business does this very thing with Marketing, and Sales.

The one thing I see as an issue is that any changes will sync immediately, not based upon location (i.e., "when they return to the office.")

Answer (score 0):

QPulse or some other document management system.

If you value your data, there is never a good reason to use Dropbox. Ever.

Here are couple of articles from the many available: http://www.zdnet.com/article/after-snowden-slams-dropbox-twice-ceo-responds-its-a-trade-off/

http://techcrunch.com/2014/10/11/edward-snowden-new-yorker-festival/

Comment: If I'm DoD, Sikorsky, Boeing, Pratt Whitney, et. al., I don't use DropBox either. If I'm SMB selling widgets to the general public, the ease of use and ubiquity of DropBox makes it an easy choice.